# Figuring out if an app supports deep links

Tags: android, ios

I'd like to easily figure out, for any app installed on my phone, if that app supports deep links (i.e. links that open the app instead of a website).

Is there a way of doing this in Android and/or iOS without having to randomly click links?

Comment: ok.. guess you just want an easy way

Comment: well, anything helps : )

Comment: there is my answer, hope you the best.. good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way works for **iOS only** and tells you if the app has an url scheme to open it

What you have to do is **get the app on itunes on your computer**.. **unzip** it and look inside for the **Info.plist** file.

This file is an XML.. look for `'URL types'`, somewhere inside this is where `'URL Schemes'` are defined.

> The sad part is that you need to do this for each app and that this
>   may change in future versions of the same app.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the apps custom scheme then you can use:

```
let url = URL(string: “fb://“)!
let isInstalled = UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
```

Here is a [blog post](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl%22blog%20post%22) for further reading.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there's a way to do this without knowing the custom scheme?

Comment: There is a private API but if you plan on putting your app onto the Store then there is no other way. There was a website that listed loads of known schemes but it seems to be down. http://handleopenurl.com